# pandas and openpyxl formatting not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, openpyxl

Just trying to format a DataFrame and save it to excel file using python3.7. I am pretty much sure am doing some noob mistake but can't figure it out.

```
styled_df = df.style.bar(['Null_Percentage'], color="#bbddbb")
styled_df.to_excel(path, engine='openpyxl', encoding='utf-8', index=False)
```

Here is the output Excel image. Ideally, there should have been bars in Null Percentage column:
[image]

I am using pandas version=0.25.0 and openpyxl=2.6.3

Comment: The documentation mentions that not all formatting features are supported when exporting to excel - https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/style.html#Export-to-Excel. `bar` formatting feature could be one of the unsupported ones.

Comment: Maybe. Thanks :)

Comment: https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/pandas.html